# Javascript on Firebase : something wrong in once("value").then();

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

[image]

To set up some cloud functions on Firebase, I started learning Javascript 2 days ago, trying to compute and store some data under the "achievementsCount_total" node (please refer to the figure for the database structure). I've succeeded in creating the node. However, the data stored under that node were not what I expected them to be. To test what's going on, I've revised my code, shown as below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.updateScores = functions.database.ref('/users/{userUID}/achievements')
.onWrite(event => {
  var database=admin.database();
  var achievementsCount_total=new Array();//not important here
  for(var i=0;i<60;i++){achievementsCount_total[i]=0;}//not important here
  var allUsersRef=database.ref("/users");//a list containing all users
  var hasChildren=123;
  allUsersRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot)//SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE!
  {
    hasChildren=snapshot.hasChildren();//either "true" or "false"
    snapshot.forEach(function(element) 
    {
      // . . . not important here
    });
  });
  return admin.database().ref("/achievementsCount_total").set(hasChildren);      
});
```

And to my surprise, the value under the node "achievementsCount_total" was neither "true" nor "false", but still "123"! This means that there was something wrong in:

```
allUsersRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot){. . .});
```

Seems like the function was not even executed (so that the variable "hasChildren" still has the value of 123), and I don't know why. Somebody knows the answer? Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allUsersRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot)//SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE!
  {
    hasChildren=snapshot.hasChildren();//either "true" or "false"
    snapshot.forEach(function(element) 
    {
      // . . . not important here
    });
  });
```

is an asynchronous function

```
return admin.database().ref("/achievementsCount_total").set(hasChildren);
```

does not wait for it to run, in order to fix this you would have to return it inside a **.then()** 
this should work

```
  return allUsersRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot)//SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE!
  {
    hasChildren=snapshot.hasChildren();//either "true" or "false"
    snapshot.forEach(function(element) 
    {
      // . . . not important here
    });
    return admin.database().ref("/achievementsCount_total").set(hasChildren);
  });
```